# Помогите с функцией Мёбиуса

Tags: c++, ооп

Помогите разобраться с классом булевых функций.
В функции anf Не срабатывает метод преобразования Мёбиуса. Почему-то выводятся одни нули.
Если просто применять функцию мёбиуса, то булева функция не меняется.
Помогите пожалуйста исправить
Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstddef>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>

// правый сдвиг
// [x/k] = (x + k - 1)/k
// по строке заполняем наооброт - Если 0001, то храним 1000

// длина l = 2^n (Как проверить, что степень двойки - отнимаем 1 и делаем конъюнкцию с нулевой операцией)
// То есть, if ((l & (l - 1)) != 0) = выход
// n = количеству младшних нулей - посчитать пачками, можно циклом по всем разрядам

class BF
{
private:
    size_t n;
    unsigned int nw;
    unsigned int *f;

public:
    BF(size_t np, int type = 0)
    {
        n = np;
        nw = ((1u << n) + 31) >> 5;

        f = new unsigned int[nw];

        switch (type)
        {
        case 0:
            if (f)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < nw; i++)
                    f[i] = 0;
            }
            break;

        case 1:
            if (f)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < nw; i++)
                    f[i] = 0;

                if (n < 5)
                {
                    int num_bytes = ((1 << n) >> 5) + 1;

                    for (int i = 0; i < num_bytes; i++)
                    {
                        f[i] = 0xFFFFFFFF; // Устанавливаем все биты в 1.
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < nw; i++)
                        f[i] = 0xFFFFFFFF;
                }
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            if (f)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < nw; i++)
                    f[i] = 0;

                if (n <= 5)
                {
                    if (n <= 5)
                    {
                        unsigned int random_value = rand() ^ (rand() << 15) ^ (rand() << 30);
                        int left_shift = 32 - (1 << n);
                        random_value >>= left_shift;
                        f[0] = random_value;
                    }
                }

                if (n > 5)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < nw; i++)
                        f[i] = rand() ^ (rand() << 15) ^ (rand() << 30);
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    BF operator=(const BF &f)
    {
        if (this == &f) // проверка на самоприсваивание
            return *this;

        delete[] this->f; // освобождаем память из-под старого указателя

        this->n = f.n;
        this->nw = f.nw;

        this->f = new unsigned int[f.nw]; // выделяем новую память под копию
        if (this->f)
        {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < f.nw; i++)
                this->f[i] = f.f[i];
        }

        return *this;
    }

    BF(const char *str)
    {
        int len_of_str = strlen(str);

        if ((len_of_str & (len_of_str - 1)) != 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Не является степенью двойки" << std::endl;
            exit(0);
        }

        int copy_len = len_of_str;
        this->n = 0;

        while (copy_len)
        {
            if ((copy_len & 1) == 0)
                this->n = this->n + 1;

            copy_len = copy_len >> 1;
        }

        this->nw = ((1 << n) + 31) >> 5;

        this->f = new unsigned int[nw];

        for (int i = 0; i < nw; i++)
        {
            f[i] = 0;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < len_of_str; ++i)
        {
            if (str[i] == '1')
            {
                f[i >> 5] |= (1 << (31 - (i % 32))); // Установить соответствующий бит в 1
            }
        }
    }

    ~BF()
    {
        if (f)
            delete[] f;
        f = nullptr;
    }

    BF(const BF &f)
    {
        this->n = f.n;
        this->nw = f.nw;
        this->f = new unsigned int[this->nw];
        for (int i = 0; i < nw; i++)
            this->f[i] = f.f[i];
    }

    int weight_of_f()
    {
        int weight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nw; i++)
        {
            unsigned int tmp = this->f[i];
            while (tmp)
            {
                tmp &= tmp - 1; // убирает самый правый установленный бит
                weight++;
            }
        }
        return weight;
    }

    void print()
    {
        int count = 0;
        if (this->f)
        {
            unsigned int mask;
            for (size_t ix_byte = 0; ix_byte < this->nw; ix_byte++)
            {
                for (unsigned int ix_bit_ltr = 0, ix_bit_rtl = 31; ix_bit_rtl >= 0 && ix_bit_ltr < 32; ix_bit_ltr++, ix_bit_rtl--)
                {
                    count++;

                    mask = 1 << ix_bit_rtl;
                    std::cout << ((this->f[ix_byte] & mask) ? 1 : 0);
                    if ((1 << n) == count)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                std::cout << " ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "NULLptr";
        }
    }

    BF prMeb()
    {
        unsigned int a;

        BF g = *this;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nw; i++) // цикл для преобазования мёбиуса для каждого слова тоже бабочка
        {
            a = this->f[i];
            a = a ^ ((a << 1u) & 0xAAAAAAAAu);
            a = a ^ ((a << 2u) & 0xCCCCCCCCu);
            a = a ^ ((a << 4u) & 0xF0F0F0F0u);
            a = a ^ ((a << 8u) & 0xFF00FF00u);
            g.f[i] = a ^ ((a << 16u) & 0xFFFF0000u);
        }
        if (n < 5)
        {
            g.f[0] &= (1u << (1 << n)) - 1u; // обнуляем незначащие биты
        }
        if (n > 5) // если переменных юольше 5 => больше одного слова то делаем бабочку снова но для слов
        {
            for (unsigned int k = 1; k < nw; k <<= 1)
            {
                for (unsigned int j = 0; j < nw; j += k << 1)
                {
                    for (unsigned int s = j; s < j + k; s++)
                    {
                        g.f[s + k] ^= g.f[s];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return g;
    }

    void anf_f()
    {
        BF prM = this->prMeb();
        std::cout << "M: ";
        prM.print();
        // Создание вектора длины n
        std::vector<int> coefficients(this->n, 0);

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < prM.nw; i++)
        {
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
            {
                unsigned int index = (i << 5) + j; // Вычисление индекса бита во временном фильтре с использованием сдвига

                if (prM.f[j] & (1u << j))
                {
                    for (unsigned int k = 0; k < this->n; k++)
                    {
                        if (coefficients[k] == 0)
                        {
                            coefficients[k] = 1; // Установка 1, если текущий коэффициент равен 0

                            break; // Выход из цикла, когда найден первый нулевой коэффициент
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Вывод коэффициентов
        for (unsigned int k = 0; k < this->n; k++)
        {
            if (coefficients[k] == 0)
            {
                std::cout << "1 "; // Если коэффициент равен 0, выводим "1"
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "x" << k << " "; // Если коэффициент не равен 0, выводим "x" и его индекс
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    // for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
    // {
    //     BF func(i, 2);
    //     if (i < 5)
    //     {
    //         func.print();
    //     }
    //     unsigned int total_combinations = 1u << i;
    //     std::cout << func.weight_of_f() << " " << (double(func.weight_of_f()) / total_combinations) << std::endl;
    // }

    const char *str = "01010011";
    BF f(str);
    f.anf_f();

    return 0;
}
```